# How to bind the Image.Source in MVVM correctly?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I spent some time now trying to work this out but I am still stuck on it. I have a WPF application with a MVVM pattern. In my ViewModel I have three cases where:

- `X needs Y` and `Y is available`
- `X needs Y` and `Y is not available`
- `X doesn't need Y`

I am trying to set an image icon on my view based on these conditions (Like a Check Mark, exclamation Mark... whatever).

**In ViewModel:**
I created my properties. On any GUI change, I set the variables based on the above cases similar to the following:

```
void MyBigFunctionToSetAllProperties()
{
   // other cases
   // ..
   if (NeedsY && YExists)
    {
        // properties
        StatusIconPath = "@\"/Resources/SessionView/X-With-Green-Check-White.png\"";
        ResultIconPath = "@\"/Resources/SessionView/Y-White.png\"";
    }
}
```

In **View.Cs**: I did literally nothing.

In **View.xaml:** I bind like this:

```
<StackPanel>
     <Image Source="{Binding StatusIconPath} />
</StackPanel>
```

I still can't see why it is not working. What is that thing that I am missing? Please and thanks.

It did not work to bind the properties directly with the Xaml as recommended. I tried it this way:

**VM:** sample property:

`public BitmapImage VerificationStatusIcon{ get { return new BitmapImage(new Uri(@VerificationStatusIconPath, UriKind.Relative));}}`

**View Xaml**:

```
<Image Name="verificationStatusImage" Source="{Binding VerificationStatusIcon}" Margin="5,0" Width="40" Height="40"/>
```

Comment: Does your view model class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and does the Setter for `StatusIconPath` raise `PropertyChanged` correctly?

Comment: @brad I use the same described routine for textBlock bindings and it is working, it is just not working for the image. Could you please look at the OP edit? thanks

Comment: Are you seeing any binding errors fly by in Visual Studio's Output window as the binding happens?  I'd also verify that the images are actually embedded correctly as resources and that the resource path you are using is correct.  Sometimes those can look really odd in WPF.

Comment: See this page for some examples of how to reference resource via path in WPF. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx  You might end up with a path looking something like `pack://application:,,,/ResourceFile.png`

Comment: @brad I added my output. Interesting, thanks. I am digging more

Comment: @brad I got it. in _View.cs_ I need to do this `verificationResultImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@WhateverImagePathIs, UriKind.Relative));`

Comment: I would be weary of that fix if you really want to learn MVVM. You may want to consider changing the binding property on the VM to URI,and seeing that in the VM Instead of code behind.

Comment: @brad ehm.. okay then why not set the VM properties to return the whole bitmapImage? and then bind it with the gui? And, you are saying that I change MV properties to return URI, but the Image.Source needs Image type right?

Comment: WPF can use converters to change several different types in to the correct property type for the binding.  The main point is, that with the MVVM pattern, you shouldn't be setting a property like that in the code behind, it should be done in the ViewModel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I have an extra unneeded characters in my *ImagePaths* as Kyle stated. And then, I needed to set my `Image.Source` from within my **View.cs**. At least, this is how it worked for me:

**ViewModel** Something like this:

```
if (Whatever)
{
    StatusIconPath = "/Resources/SessionView/X-With-Green-Check-White.png";
    ResultIconPath = "/Resources/SessionView/Y-White.png";
}
```

Then in **View.cs** and on `SelectedItemChanged`:

```
private void Grid_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string tempStatus = ((SessionViewModel) DataContext).StatusIconPath;
    string tempResult = ((SessionViewModel) DataContext).ResultIconPath;
    StatusImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@tempStatus, UriKind.Relative));
    ResultImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@tempResult, UriKind.Relative));
}
```

and in **Xaml:** just a fallback value(any original/default image we want). Ex:

```
<Image Name="ResultImage" Source="/EZ3D;component/Resources/SessionView/Retake-White.png"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a whole bunch of unnecessary characters in your icon paths:

```
StatusIconPath = "@\"/Resources/SessionView/X-With-Green-Check-White.png\"";
ResultIconPath = "@\"/Resources/SessionView/Y-White.png\"";
```

Change them to this:

```
StatusIconPath = "Resources/SessionView/X-With-Green-Check-White.png";
ResultIconPath = "Resources/SessionView/Y-White.png";
```

Comment: Use full Resource File Pack URIs, like `"pack://application:,,,/Resources/SessionView/Y-White.png"`, and make sure that the Build Action of the image files is set to `Resource`.

Comment: @Clemens While the full pack URIs is likely safer, I tested the local strings as the OP had in a test project and had no issues.  As long as it's within the same assembly it should be fine.

Comment: This is correct, Kyle. But then, I needed to set my `Image.Source = new BitMapImage(new Uri(@WhateverThisPathIs, UriKind.Relative));` in my View.cs. I will edit my OP to include that

Comment: And the path needs a `/` at the very beginning. Like this: `"/Resources/..."`

Comment: @FirstStep I'm not sure why that would be.  I tested this solution exactly as I have it here and it worked fine without the leading slash and without explicitly creating an `ImageSource` (which actually surprised me, I didn't think the binding engine would perform that particular conversion).

Comment: It is working right now, and exactly as I wanted. so I set path string in VM, then use that path in View.cs: to create a new BitmapImage and assign it to the ImageElement.Source .. I am not sure if this is called Binding but I feel that I did not do it right..

Answer (score 1):

> . But no images originally to view and no changes..

Verify that the path to the image is correct. Maybe hard code an image to test the control against it.

One other scenario is that the resources are not being copied over for run-time acquisition. Make sure they are actually available during runtime.

> can't see why it is not working

Is the main view's DataContext set to the live VM's instance?

> What is that thing that I am missing?

If you are sure that the view's datacontext contains the live VM, then make sure that the property `StatusIconPath` on the VM reports a *property change event*.

That is so that the XAML control which is bound to it knows that it changed and correspondingly one needs to make sure that the ViewModel *which holds `StatusIconPath`* adheres to `INotifyPropertyChanged` which will facilitate such an operation in general:

```
private string _StatusIconPath;

public string StatusIconPath 
{
   get { return _StatusIconPath; }
   set
       {
       _StatusIconPath = value;
       PropertyChanged("StatusIconPath");
       }
}
```

I provide more robust example on my blog entitled:

[Xaml: ViewModel Main Page Instantiation and Loading Strategy for Easier Binding](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1017)

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, because it is working with TextBlock binding. Could you please look at the OP edit? thanks

Comment: @FirstStep I updated my answer...it sounds like the image location may not be able to be resolved.

Comment: The image files are in the solution's resources and I see them in the folder explorer. Still not working. I added my output if you could analyze that please. I am digging more now

Comment: @FirstStep it looks like the resources are either not being copied over (for runtime) or the pathing is wrong to the file.

Comment: I got it working if you want to edit and reflect that. Thanks for your help